# Wi-Fi direct maximum number of devices

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi, wifi-direct

I'm developing an application based on WiFi Direct that connects multiple devices to start sharing files, up til now I've experimented with 3-4 devices, What's the maximum number of devices that a group can hold?